# Dynamic Multiple Font load as per env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I've one file font.css where multiple fonts are loaded but i need to make dynamic font path as per the env file so how can we achieve that in react

You can suggest me the feasible solutions.

I've tried by creating an font.scss file and declared global variable in the default.js
which i'm trying to access in scss but unable to get

Answer (score 1):

The loadFont method below allows you to load font into document dynamically.

```html
<h1>This is a test message</h1>

<form>
    <div>
        <input id="family">Family</input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="url">Url</input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    async function loadFont (family, url, options) {
        const fontFace = new FontFace(family, `url(${url})`, options);
        const loadedFont = await fontFace.load();
        document.fonts.add(loadedFont);
    }

    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const family = document.getElementById("family").value;
        const url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        console.log(family, url)
        await loadFont(family, url)
        document.querySelector("h1").style.fontFamily = family
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I need solution in the react if you can suggest

Comment: Simply call loadFont in any point of your react application